# Update secret value across accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I wrote a Python script on a function in one account that tries to get a secret value from a second account using boto3 with `client.get_secret_value()`. However, `client.update_secret()` only seems to be working for secrets in the same account, not secrets in the second account.

```
secretUpdated = client.update_secret(
    SecretId=’arn for my test secret',
    Description='',
    KmsKeyId='kms key arn’,
    SecretString='the Secret string for my test secret with key values'
)
```

I get back `Access denied` but as far as I can tell it should have `secretsmanager:UpdateSecret` both from the function in the first account and to the secret in the other account with it being set in all the same places I added `getsecret` (function policy on role and the resource policy on the secret) so I don't know if there are any extra parameters I need to add to the script when it is cross-account?

Answer (score 0):

Secrets can only be accessed/updated in the account associated with the IAM credentials that you are using. (Otherwise, I would be able to view/change the secrets in *your* account!)

You have two options:

**Option 1: Use credentials associated with the 'other' account**

Obtain an Access Key and Secret Key for an IAM User in the 'other' account that has permissions to use Secrets Manager. Then, use those credentials with boto3. This can be done in a couple of ways:

- Store the credentials as a **different profile**, using `aws configure --profile account2`
- Then use the profile like this:

```py
import boto3

session = boto3.Session(profile_name='account2')
secrets_client = session.client('secretsmanager')
```

OR

- Pass the credentials to the client with:

```py
import boto3

secrets_client = boto3.client('secretsmanager', aws_access_key_id='AKIAxxx', aws_secret_access_key='xyz')
```

The `secrets_client` will then be accessing the other account.

See: [Credentials — Boto3 Docs documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html)

**Option 2: Assume an IAM Role in the 'other' account**

- Create an IAM Role in the 'other' account and grant it permissions for Secrets Manager
- Add a Trust Policy to the IAM Role that allows it to be 'assumed' by the IAM User in your 'normal' account
- Using boto3, call `assume_role()` to assume the IAM Role in the other account

```py
import boto3
from boto3.session import Session


client = boto3.client('sts')

response = client.assume_role(RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::00000000000000:role/example-role`, RoleSessionName='account2')
     
session = Session(aws_access_key_id='AKIAxxx', aws_secret_access_key='xyz')
secrets_client = session.client('secretsmanager')
```

See: [Switching to an IAM role (AWS API) - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-api.html)

Comment: Im currently accessing the secret useing resource permissions the secret and the kms key it uses in the 2nd account has permissions allowing the role from the first to access them with that role being the role attached to the lambda function in the first account.

The issue is i only seem to be able to get the secret value and not update it.

are you saying that i can read it useing resorce permissions but to update it i will need to get the function to assume a role in the account with the secret in it?